# aws lambda environment variable initiate outside handler

Tags: environment-variables, aws-lambda, handler

I am calling an environment variable outside handler and initializing a variable to be available in a global scope so multiple methods can reuse them.my handler is triggered by s3 event hence environment variable that i set outside handler become useless, can anyone let me know if its possible to have a variable initialized outside handler
Thanks

```
 masterkey = environ['accesstoken']
`print("environment variable: " + environ['accesstoken'])

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   ........
   ........
```

Comment: You lost me here: "my handler is triggered by s3 event hence environment variable that i set outside handler become useless" Why is it useless in this scenario? The Lambda function should always have access to any environment variables you setup for the function, regardless of how the function is invoked or what triggered the invocation. As your code is currently, `masterkey` is a global variable and should be accessible from any method. What is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Comment: when the program is executed , the above print command never executed and looks like masterkey is never initialized.whereever i access the masterkey inside sub method keep .my current solution would be to initialize the variable inside the lambda_handler method and pass it to sub method calls . `NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.`

Comment: I don't think you understand how Lambda container reuse works. That print statement won't happen every time, only the first time the function runs, but the variable will be set globally, and available every time the handler method is called. I suggest debugging your Lambda function further to track down the actual issue.

Comment: thanks i figured out the actual issue